# Vertical Scroll Bar and Viewport Positioning

Tags: java, jscrollpane

I am using a JTextPane in conjunction with a JScrollPane.  The JTextPane is pre-populated with a large amount of text which needs scrolling to read.  The problem I am having is that the view port is displaying the bottom-most part of the text by default - ie the vertical scroll bar knob is positioned at the bottom (rather than the top) when the JFrame opens or is refreshed. I have not had this problem when I have used the JScrollPane previously.

This is the code I used to create the scroll pane: -

```
    JTabbedPane jtpCentre = new JTabbedPane();

    JPanel panHexagramText = new JPanel();
    panHexagramText.setBorder(bor);
    txpHexagramText = new JTextPane();
    txpHexagramText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(595, 300));
    scrHTPanel = new JScrollPane(txpHexagramText,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);      
    scrHTPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(595,300));

    panHexagramText.add(scrHTPanel);
```

The code I use to populate the text pane is located in a different class:

```
     try {
        String strLineText = this.createLineTextString(strLineTextData);
        String[] strFullText = {"Hexagram Text\n\n",
            strTranslationData[0][1],
            "\n\nLine Text",
            strLineText};
        String[] strStyles = {"bold", "regular", "bold", "regular"};
        gui.txpHexagramText.setText(null);
        StyledDocument sDoc = gui.txpHexagramText.getStyledDocument();
        this.addStylesToDoc(sDoc);
        for (int i = 0; i < strFullText.length; i++) {
            sDoc.insertString(sDoc.getLength(), strFullText[i],
                    sDoc.getStyle(strStyles[i]));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {// Trap error if there is no translation available.
        gui.txpHexagramText.setText(str);
    }
```

I would like to ask why it is doing this, and how I can correct it?

Many thanks.